# Hibernate: optional attribute in composite natural primary key

Tags: hibernate, composite-primary-key, optional-values

I'm experiencing an issue with Hibernate. I have an Entity mapped to a table with a natural composite primary key. The primary key consists of a mandatory code and either an optional Date or Period ID, so date and period_id are mutual exclusive. I mapped it in my hbm (yes, no annotations for us yet) like:

```
    <composite-id name="myEntity" class="myEntity">
        <key-property name="code" column="bookcode" />
        <key-property name="period" column="PRD_ID" />
        <key-property name="pDate" column="PNL_DT"/>
    </composite-id>
```

But doing a query on a myEntity where the date is not null, and the period is null fails to populate myEntity Object. I can't see why its failing, but I can see that hibernate stops logging the returned attributes after the NULL value for period is returned.

```
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet:151 - binding '1157' to parameter: 4
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet:193 - returning '1157' as column: LVE1_69_
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet:187 - returning null as column: PRD2_69_
END OF LOGGING
```

Removing PeriodId  key-property solves he issue and myEntity is successful populated.

```
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet:151 - binding '1156' to parameter: 4
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet:193 - returning '1156' as column: LVE1_69_
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet:193 - returning '2012-04-06 00:00:00' as column: PNL2_69_
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet:193 - returning '1156' as column: LVE1_69_
LOTS MORE RETURNING lines.
```

I would suspect a not-null="false" attribute in the key-property but I couldn't find this inside the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

since the id corresponds to the primary key in the database which is not null by default Hibernate considers them the same. If code is unique on it's own then declare it as id and leave the other 2 as normal many-to-one

Comment: the code is not unique, the combination with period_id OR date is unique, its a valid unique constraint in the database. So the composite_id is not null, but consists of one optional (nullable) attribute.

Comment: but it is no valid primary key which is the equivalent of id in NHibernate. Also i once had a problem with postgres where a unique constraint over columns with nulls is disabled until the nulls are removed

Comment: Thanks for your reactions, I'm not sure whether a composite id with optional attributes is a valid primary key, any references? In this case the primary key is not really necessary as the record is not referenced anywhere. BTW I solved the problem by adding a surrogate auto increment PK but I still see this as polluting your datamodel.